# Iterate over each row in pandas data frame and make changes to it

Tags: python, pandas, loops, nlp

I'm building a text classification algorithm, for which (in pandas data frame) I need to go through each row of a particular column, each row of the column contains a group of strings. I need to check each word in the row and see if it is present in a pre-defined dictionary. If it is, I will do some operation with that word. Else, I will remove that word from string.
Here's the code I used for it:

```
onehotmess=[]
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    sum=np.zeros(dim,dtype=float)
    for acr in row['message']:
        index=np.where(Acr_array==acr)
        if len(index)==0:
            messages=messages.str.replace(acr,"",case=False)
        else:
            sum=sum+onehot_encoded[index]
            onehotmess.append(sum)
```

But it's taking a lot of time, and eventually, my system got crashed. Is it a correct implementation. If so, I need some other efficient method.
If not, please help with the correct code.
The dictionary (Acr_array) contains acronyms:

> array(['ABN', 'ABV', 'ACC', 'ACCUM', 'ACFT', 'ACR', 'ACT', 'ADJ'...
>   'WKDAYS', 'WKEND', 'WND', 'WPT','WSR', 'WTR', 'WX'])

Sample input:

> TWY G BTN RWY CC AND RWY LR WIP CONST

This is present in a row under 'message' column in pandas data frame.

Output:

> OneHot_encoded[idx(TWY)] OneHot_encoded[idx(BTN)]
>   OneHot_encoded[idx(RWY)] OneHot_encoded[idx(AND)]
>   OneHot_encoded[idx(RWY)] OneHot_encoded[idx(WIP)]

Output doesn't have G,CC,LR,CONST as they are not in Acr_array. idx('') is position of that acronym in Acr_array. So the output contains the value at that position in OneHot_encoded.

Comment: provide sample data and expected output